# Html css Card aligment

Tags: html, css

I need to show the image in the right side of card how can i do this ? not by margin-left because If title size is more then the image will show in next line

```
<div class="block_container1">
  <div  class="tit" *ngFor="let c of cdata">{{c.name}}</div>
  <div  style="text-align: right;"><img  src="assets/imgs/32.png"></div>
</div>

.block_container1 > div {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Put it before the name and float it to the right? Or use flexbox? Or absolute positioning?

Comment: Please provide us with [MCVE] so that we might be able to help you out with whatever you have already tried. We can only guess some methods that might help you at this point. This [example](https://jsfiddle.net/zr1ksb4y/) is all I can make from your code.

Comment: Easiest way is to absolute position the logo into the relative grey container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<div>` element containing the `<img>` element could be set to float to the right by making use of the CSS property `float: right;`. Keep in mind to clear the `float` property for the next `<div>` element.For proper alignment use `line-height` for your `<div>` elements

Below is a working snippet:

```css
.block_container1>div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.tit {
  line-height: 38px
}

.myImg {
  float: right;
  line-height: 38px
}
```

```html
<div class="block_container1">
  <div class="tit" *ngFor="let c of cdata">hello</div>
  <div class="myImg"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/smiley.gif"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Care to explain to OP what you are trying to show? Like what piece of code above would be of importance to OP? You and I know what the above means, however just copying and pasting code does not make OP understand what is going on.

Comment: @Barrosy Please check it as I have mentioned to float the div containing image to right. That doesn't need more explanation i guess

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to make the image the background of your block_container1 class, mark the background-position as "top right", and make sure it doesn't repeat:

```css
.example { 
  min-height:500px;
  background-image:url('https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fabric-features-clothes-materials-glyph/64/41_design-sample-color-palette-128.png'); 
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:top right;
  margin:40px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="example">

  <h2>Example</h2>
  
  This is an example.
  
</div>
```

You can add padding around the image by giving .block_container1 a margin.  You can [learn more about background positions here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp).

Comment: What would be the advantage(s) and disadvantage(s) of using CSS property `background-image` rather than an `<img>` element and positioning it though?

Answer (score 0):

Try the `flexbox` approach:

```css
.block_container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
 }
```

```html
<div class="block_container1">
  <div  class="tit" *ngFor="let c of cdata">{{c.name}}</div>
  <div  style="text-align: right;"><img  src="assets/imgs/32.png"></div>
</div>
```